# Cant Connect to Database

Tags: database

Odd..

Via SSH terminal I can manual connect to the DB using the username / password

I also added `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` and ran the `repair and optimize option`

I also ran the `wp db repair` from command line.

I can connect to the db using PhpMyAdmin.

I deactivated all plugins.

I even went in through PMA and verified that the wp_options table has the correct site url.

Anybody know what I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any errors in connection settings in the wp-config.php?

Comment: I am absolutely sure. username, password, db name, and db host are all correct. I have verified this multiple times.

Comment: I just imported a 10 day old backup with the same exact credentials in wp-config.php and I now have access to my site again.  I greatly interested what could possibly cause this problem?

Comment: Personally, I would import the problematic backup again and examine the error.log. Also, I would compare wp-config.php from both backups with git diff or another tool.

Comment: I didn't change the wp-config.php file at all.  so there is nothing to diff.     I imported a 2 week .sql...  And now everything works.  I have not worked on the site in the last 2 weeks, so it is as if something "inside" the db was somehow preventing the connection. which I can only imagine came from an update.  I will activate the debug.log and apahe2 error logs... but this beyond strange